# php search bar with filter list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search bar wich finds a job and I want to give the opportunity to filter the result by selected city or/and category.

This is my PHP code so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $job = $_POST['search'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $category = $_POST['category']; 

    $query ="SELECT jobname, city, category FROM table_jobs WHERE jobname LIKE '%$job%'";

    if($city != "Chose City") {
        $query .=" AND city LIKE '%$city%'";
    }
    if($ategory != "Chose Category"){
        $query .=" AND category LIKE '%$category%'";
    }

    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = "No results!";
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $titlu = $row['jobname'];
            $companie = $row['numefirma'];
            $oras = $row['numeoras'];   
            $domeniu = $row['numedomeniu'];

             $output .=<<<HTML
             <table id="anunt">
             <tr>
             <td class='left'><a href='' style="color: blue">$titlu</a><br>Companie:        $companie<br>Domeniu: $domeniu</td>
             <td class='right'>$oras</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             HTML;
        }
     }
 }
```

The search bar looks like [this](http://s12.postimg.org/t3rrwzvq5/Capture.png)

How can I make my filter lists work? I have my city tables in my database and category table (with work categories like IT software, marketing etc)

Comment: A. [You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and 2.
Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You have a typo `if($ategory`.

Comment: can you please explain what's not working?